# Changing/Processing data after async fetch in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to change data after fetching them in componentDidMount function.

Let's say I'm fetching one object:

```
{
  text: "hello world"
}
```

​but I want to add "!" to this string after fetching in componentDidMount.
My question si, where should I edit fetched data?
When I'm trying to edit it in componentDidMount I always get error saying that I cannot edit 'undefined'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be a little more specific, its better if you show your fetch function and your modify function also. But, I can guess something similar to it:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch(reqObj)
      .then(json => {
        const modifyJson = JSON.stringify(json) + '!'
        this.setState({text: modifyJson})
      })
  }
```

Comment: I guess the OP wants to append `!` to `hello world`, not to the JSON blob. But generally the right idea.

Comment: I figured out that the best solution to this problem would be to edit data coming from server in action creator. I didn't think about that.

What do you think about that idea?

Comment: It is how I do in my project :)